# Lost iPhone not connected to Find My iPhone!

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Lost my iPhone and it wasn't connected to Find My iPhone, how can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly turned Find My iPhone off, it was on. Try this anyway: go to iCloud.com/find and sign into your iCloud account using your Apple ID. Click Find my iPhone. Choose Locate an iOS device. If it is turned on, and the phone is still online, it will show you on a map. If it does not, then either you *did* turn off Find my iPhone or it is offline. If either of those is the case, it's time to visit the Apple Store and buy a new iPhone.

Comment: Offline is completely different to Find my iPhone not being on at all.

Comment: I know that. Offline = battery dead, off, or airplane mode. Not on = he did not turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay small change to the post above you could contact your sim carrier who can help you locate your phone through tracking.